# record not inserted in database sqlite

Tags: android

I have 2 text field user name and password and a button in same view I filled these two text box and click the submit button for inserting the data in the data base, but it is failed for inserting in sqlite data base I am also pasting my Log cat below. Please take a look where is the problem: why it is not inserting it database? Thanks.

```
    public class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
public static final String USER_NAME = "USER_NAME";
public static final String PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";

private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;

public DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Users.db";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "User";

private static final String TAG = "MyContentProvider";

public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

ava:150)
       06-30 12:22:49.622: ERROR/JavaBinder(235):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:140)
     06-30 12:22:49.622: ERROR/JavaBinder(235):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:287)
         06-30 12:22:49.622: ERROR/JavaBinder(235):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
       06-30 12:22:55.271: DEBUG/dalvikvm(235): GC freed 542 objects / 51288 bytes in 152ms
```

Comment: Thanx Alex for improving questioning..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the password as text, 'PASS' doesn't exist in sqlite, so there is probably some error when creating the table. Try this:

```
 db.execSQL("Create table "
            + TABLE_NAME
            + "( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, USER_NAME TEXT,PASSWORD TEXT);");
```

If you don't want to store the password in a readable format you will obviously have to encrypt it first.

Comment: error is coming in this stuff   sqlDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  // insert record in user table and get the row number of recently inserted record
  long rowId = sqlDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, "",contentvalues);
  if (rowId > 0) {
   Uri rowUri = ContentUris.appendId(
     MyUsers.User.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon(), rowId).build();
   getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(rowUri, null);
   return rowUri;
  }
  throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the chapter ContentProvides in [Learning Android (O'Reilly)](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449390501/Android_Content_Providers.html). There you can learn everything you need to know.

- You have to close the db after writing!